# Considerations in Writing a Web Application off a Scraper

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping

I am currently trying to write a small application that will essentially parasite off of the information of another website (my school's grade portal), basically to make the content on the other site more useful. I have a proof-of-concept written up in Ruby and Mechanize right now.

I am, however, trying to figure out where to go from here. Running the proof-of-concept takes a *long* time, sometimes up to a minute to complete logging in. I don't suspect that I can make it much faster because of the way the website is written (it's old).

What should I be concerned about when trying to turn this proof-of-concept into a full-blown app?

Comment: "What should I be concerned about when trying to turn this proof-of-concept into a full-blown app?"  How much you're going to piss off your school.  On a helpful note though: You may want to consider doing the scraping behind the scenes though and then only displaying the data to the user once you have it instead of having the user wait (assuming it's not the actual login that takes forever).

Comment: Yes..caching the scrape results is the way to solve the slowness issue. Run a Rake task or similar that scrapes the pages once every hour or whatever interval is appropriate (not too frequent to distrupt the website), and then always run the front-end off this scraped data.

Answer (score 0):

When you're scraping, you're basically playing at the other kid's house. They can (and will) change things at their leisure. You will need extensive error checking. I suggest you scrape and save the data to a staging environment before publishing it, and make sure your users are aware their may be intermittent delays in getting data while you frantically try to recover your scraping routine after a site change.